# Installed pip, but can't find where the virtualenvwrapper_bashrc

Tags: python, pip

How can I find out where the virtualenvwrapper_bashrc file is?

I'm looking in:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin
```

But I don't see it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You say that you installed `pip`, but you don't say whether or not you installed `virtualenvwrapper`, which is neither included with `pip` nor `virtualenv`.

If you have installed `virtualenvwrapper` using

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

or something similar, then you can use the following to find where it is located:

```
$ which virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

In ver 1.x, the file was called `virtualenvwrapper_bashrc`; however, Doug Hellmann—the creator of virtualenvwrapper—changed the name to `virtualenvwrapper.sh` starting in version 2.x.

Comment: ok for some reason it is in: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh is that "correct"?  do I need to add this to my PATH?  little confused as to what I have to modify in my .bash_profile